# bash restart mysql when it gone run well in SSH part, but not in cronjob

Tags: bash, centos, cron, mysql

My system is centos 6.5,

I write a simple bash shell to check if mysql is crashed, restart service again. I put it in `/home/myspace/mysql.sh` `chown root:root /home/myspace/mysql.sh` then run every minute by crontab.

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql --host="localhost" --user="root" --password="password" --database="test" --execute="select id from test limit 1"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo "";
else
 /usr/bin/sudo service mysql stop
 pkill mysql
 /usr/bin/sudo service mysql start
 echo "error $(date)" >> /home/myspace/restart_log.txt
fi
```

Now I have 2 questions.

1. Why in my code, `if ... else ...` not working? I mean the mysql server has no problem, it can execute `"select id from test limit 1"` and get result, but the script still run the code in `else` case.
2. in `/var/log/sucure`, it show `root : sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo ; TTY=unknown ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/service mysql stop`. `root : sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo ; TTY=unknown ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/service mysql start`.  And the mysql server is down.

**UPDATE:**
Now I tried the code @Anthon given:

```
#!/bin/bash
RESULT=`mysql --host="localhost" --user="root" --password="password" --database="test" --execute="select browser from test limit 1"`
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then 
   echo "mysql select ok"
else
  /usr/bin/echo "mysql select failed"
  sudo service mysql stop
  pkill mysql
  /usr/bin/sudo service mysql start
  echo "error $(date)" >> /home/myspace/restart_log.txt
fi
```

it works well in `SSH` part (return mysql select ok)

but not working in `cronjob`(every minute write error in `/home/myspace/restart_log.txt` and mysql server never start)

Is this problem caused by `PATH`? OR `privileges`? How to solve it? thanks.

**solve**
Thanks for all, finally I solved it. @Sigi's method maybe good, but not working in my situation. @Anthon's answer write better than I, but still not working. @Emmanuel, given the answer is more nearer than other's. After a long time test, I shared final working code to all.

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
# cronjob need clear where is the path
# mysql under path /usr/local/bin
mysql --host="localhost" --user="root" --password="password" --database="test" --execute="select id from test limit 1"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo "";
# mysql run well nothing to do, make a
else
 sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
 pkill /usr/local/bin/mysql
# It should be pkill /usr/local/bin/mysql, not pkill mysql, wrong write will cause below code not working
 sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
 sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart
# Some strange behave, after mysql restart, apache will die, so should add httpd restart 
 echo "error $(date)" >> /home/myspace/restart_log.txt
fi
```

Comment: The question seems to be wrong. The `if...else` is obviously working. Your question is: Why does the `mysql` command not exit with code 0? You should make the second question a separate question as they are not related.

Comment: @Hauke Laging, thanks, so where is the problem? why the else part also working?

Comment: You seem to be running the cronjob with root (considering your 2nd question). You don't need the sudo then. Just remove "/usr/bin/sudo" in front of the service calls. It should save you from the TTY problem of sudo.

Comment: @0xAF, Now first i doubt crontab connect mysql is wrong, because even the server is run well, it still jump into else case, `echo "error $(date)" >> /home/myspace/restart_log.txt`. but it works directly in `SSH` part. thanks.

Comment: try changing this line: **RESULT=\`mysql --host="localhost" --user="root" --password="password" --database="test" --execute="select browser from test limit 1"\`**, to this: **`RESULT=\`mysql --host="localhost" --user="root" --password="password" --database="test" --execute="select browser from test limit 1" 1>/tmp/mysql.debug 2>&1\``** and see the output in /tmp/mysql.debug

Comment: @cj333 Do you get an error at all? Do you (or the user the cronjob runs as) get any email output from the cronjob. Most likely you need to extend your PATH in the script, or in the cronjob.

Comment: Do you really need to stop and start the service using `sudo` if this job is installed at crontab as root? - Based on your logs(`root : sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo ; TTY=unknown`) my 2 cents goes to a service that can´t start because you have no tty while sudoing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force the PATH in your script, cron may not provides the same path as the one you have in a terminal session.

EDIT:
In a terminal get your PATH:

```
env | grep "^PATH="   
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:...   (you will have different value
```

Cut and paste that line in your script just bellow the `#!/bin/bash`

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:     (put your path 
export PATH
```

(thats just for instance)

There may be other variable to add in your script; look for variable which names contain the 'MYSQL' string with `env | grep MYSQL` and `set | grep MYSQL`

Comment: so how to force it? how to set the right path?

Answer (score 4):

Want you want to do is check if the database server process is still alive.  MySQL provides a command for that: `mysqladmin ping`

I suggest you put the following into your system crontab (edit the file `/etc/crontab`):

```
* * * * *  root  /usr/bin/mysqladmin --host="localhost" --user="root" --password="password" ping || /usr/sbin/service mysql restart
```

This will ping the database every minute, and issue a "restart" if it does not respond.

It is not necessary to query an arbitrary table and test the result to determine if the database is alive.

Here is what the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqladmin.html) has to say about the *ping* subcommand:

> **ping**
>   Check whether the server is available. The return status from mysqladmin is 0 if the server is running, 1 if it is not. This is 0 even in case of an error such as Access denied, because this means that the server is running but refused the connection, which is different from the server not running.

Even better would be to use a dedicated process watcher (such as *monit*, *upstart* or *systemd*) to keep the *mysql* process alive.

Comment: maybe i made some mistake when i installed mysql, there is no `mysqladmin` in `/usr/bin/`, so i tried and write some bash script by myself. thanks.

Comment: `mysqladmin` is part of the official distribution of MySQL.  It really should be on your system, and if it isn't you should fix that.  It might not be in `/usr/bin` though, could be some other place (depending on how you installed it).  Change the paths in the `cron` entry accordingly.  Don't try to implement your own workaround for this (chances are you end up with a sub-par solution).

Comment: it is real not in my `/usr/bin/` folder, so how to fix it? yum? or other process?

Comment: It should be in your path.  Do `which mysqladmin` to find out where.  If you installed mysql with `yum`, then it's not going to be in `/opt` or `/usr/local`.  Maybe CentOS has a separate package containing it.  Check the list of packages related to `mysql`.

Comment: I tired `which mysqladmin`, return `/usr/bin/which: no mysqladmin in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)` and no `mysqladmin` in `/usr/local` or `/opt`

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you here.  On my distribution (Debian), the `mysqladmin` tool is installed as part of the `mysql-client` package.

Comment: `yum install mysql-client` -> `Loaded plugins: downloadonly, fastestmirror`,`base | 3.7 kB 00:00  extras | 3.4 kB     00:00 updates | 3.4 kB     00:00` `Setting up Install Process  No package mysql-client available.  Error: Nothing to do`

Comment: The package is called differently on CentOS.  Debian and CentOS are completely different distributions.

Comment: Try this: `yum provides mysqladmin`. This should show you what the name of the package is that you have to install.

Comment: Thanks now `mysqladmin` is in my server, but your code not working in cron code. ps: i have put my mysql password in it.

Comment: Try the command line from the cron job manually.  Does it work then?  Does it restart MySQL if you have killed it?  What error message does it display?

Answer (score 3):

As your log indicates (point 2), the `else` part is being executed, but just exits in the first statement.

If you want to debug something that you suspect is not being executed, make sure you echo at the beginning of both paths (you can always remove these when things work). Your empty echo in the `if` part is not helpful, would it print something, you would have noticed that that is not printed, but better would be to have an `echo "takeing else route"` on the line after the `else`.

To get `sudo` to work, you probably have to edit your `/etc/sudoers` file and comment out `requiredtty` (from the man page):

```
requiretty      If set, sudo will only run when the user is logged in
                to a real tty.  When this flag is set, sudo can only be
                run from a login session and not via other means such
                as cron(8) or cgi-bin scripts.  This flag is off by
                default.
```

To get feedback your script should look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql --host="localhost" --user="root" --password="password" --database="test" --execute="select id from test limit 1"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then 
   echo "mysql select ok"
else
   echo "mysql select failed"
 /usr/bin/sudo service mysql stop
 pkill mysql
 /usr/bin/sudo service mysql start
 echo "error $(date)" >> /home/myspace/restart_log.txt
fi
```

Comment: thanks your explain, so how to modify my code for it run well?

Comment: @cj333 change the existing echo as I indicated, add another in the else part and change the `sudoers` file. What is unclear about that?

Comment: both my english and bash skill are not good, can you correnct my code and parse it in your Answer? Thanks.

Comment: I updated my code in question. pls go on helping me. thanks.

Comment: @cj333 did you change your /etc/sudoers file?

Comment: how to do that? another way, I am thinking `if [ $? -eq 0 ]` condition, it seems wrong. how to check if mysql connection well or no?

Comment: @cj333 Edit your `/etc/sudoers` file and comment out where the `requiretty` option is set by putting a `#` in front of that line.

Comment: `/etc/sudoers` no such files or folder.

Comment: @cj333 look at the man pages for `sudo` and `sudoers` those should give you a clue as to where the sudoers file is stored on your system. Or ask your system-administrator, you should get one if your organisation  doen't have one.

Comment: thanks for your update anwser, I test code in ssh, it show "mysql select ok" nothing write in `/home/myspace/restart_log.txt` but if i add it into crontab, every minute it will write report into `/home/myspace/restart_log.txt`, now i doubt the privileges or permission that the crontab connection mysql. I have done `chown root:root /home/myspace/mysql.sh` and in `crontab -e` `* * * * * /bin/sh /home/myspace/mysql.sh >/dev/null 2>&1`.

Comment: it works perfectly in ssh, but cron do not recognize the commond codes.  I serched in google, I found the problem, It should be set path in bash code. Do you know how to set them? I treid some after google search, but still not working.

Answer (score 2):

Off-topic:
Do you really want to restart the service every minute?
When the services fails due to some other failure, trying to restart every minute is terrible. (Never delete the test-database...)
(You might make a smarter script that checks for the last failur time and waits at least 1 hour before retrying and mailing an operator)
On-topic:
When you can't depend on the returnvalue of mysql, you can try to select some string:

```
FLAG="$(mysql --host="localhost" --user="root" --password="password" --database="test" \
   --execute="select count(*) as MYSPECIALFLAG from test")"
if [[ ${FLAG} != *MYSPECIALFLAG* ]]; then
   my_restart_function
fi
```

Other question:
sudo without terminal:
Restarting the service is the responsibility of root. The system administrator running root would like to check his own crontab when something is restarting the service every minute.
So convince your system administrator that he wants to run your magic script as root,
and you do not have problems with sudo.

Comment: indeed, i only want to check mysql server every minute, only it runs not well then restart. not restart every minute. thanks. And sometimes, if no `sudo`, the `service mysql stop.....................................` it seems dead.

Comment: I understand you do not want to restart every minute, but that's what will be happening when the disk is full, the database is renamed or the database useraccount (root??) has changed it's password.

Answer (score 0):

MOST LIKELY - you need to specify the correct service, on CENTOS 6.5 it would be

`service mysqld stop`

not

`service mysql stop`

This would also be why pkill is not working, you would need `pkill mysqld`

But the real command to use is `service mysqld restart` and **avoid** using pkill altogether.

Other general notes when running through cron:

1) On CentOS 6.5, the path to echo is /bin/echo

2) If you run cron as root, do not run the commands through sudo (this will avoid tty/pty, environment, and permission problems sudo can introduce)

3) Specify the full path to pkill = /usr/bin/pkill on CentOS 6.5

4) Specify the path to mysql = /usr/bin/mysql on CentOS 6.5

As Emmanuel alludes to, there are probably not enough paths defined in PATH variable when run through cron. Generally, give the full path to all commands.